# How to format the date and time at runtime via NgxMatDateFormats

Tags: angular

To format the date and time from the date and time picker we need to create a `const` with the desired date and time format like this:

```
const CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS: NgxMatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: "L, LT"
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm",
    monthYearLabel: "MMM YYYY",
    dateA11yLabel: "LL",
    monthYearA11yLabel: "MMMM YYYY"
  }
};
```

And in the `@Component` section it needs to be set as provider like this:

```
providers: [
    { provide: NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS } // Custom Date Format
  ]
```

But how can I set the date and time format dynamically.
For example I have set the date and time format in the user settings and want to use this format here.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the [Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Does this solve my problem? As I see in the docs these are predefined formats, but I want that the user can select from different formats.
Otherwise, I can use instead "L, LT" for this. So I get always the locale date and time format.
Or did I missunderstood you?